# Flush smtp Queue

Tags: smtp, iis-6

The smtp server I use for my application was offline temporarily, but because the rest of my application was still working, it has added quite a few items in the queue. I do not want these emails to be sent out once server goes back online. How can I flush the smtp queue?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480390.aspx

Basically, you need to find your MailRoot directory and there will be a folder called "Queue"